What should we list in the "Ask about..." / "Don't ask about..." section of /about?
The moderators can edit the content of the two boxes under the Get answers to practical, detailed questions section of our /about page.
I just added some text to indicate that self help questions and questions seeking medical advice should not be asked. I'd love suggestions for improving the wording as well as anything else we think should be in these two boxes.
What should we list in the "Ask about..." and "Don't ask about..." sections of the "ABout" page?

Might want to look at the question selection for that page too, the default "unicorns and daisies" question is showing right now.

Thanks for the heads up @Mat! Looks like I'll need to contact a team member about this one.

Former list (here):


Anything not directly related to cognitive sciences 
"Self Help" questions which are personal in nature 
Questions that are primarily opinion-based 
Questions seeking medical or professional advice 
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer


New current list (here):


Pseudoscience or fiction 
Questions that do not provide relevant references or clarify underlying assumptions
"Self Help" questions which are personal in nature, seeking medical or professional advice 
Questions that are primarily opinion-based 
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer



For context, this answer got posted as part of the recent introduction of a new close vote reason focusing on a slightly more scientific target audience.
